# Redirect File to another location incase IF condition is TRUE in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code which reads a nested JSON file and return TRUE or FALSE based on condition for the FUNCTIONS (such as Source, Operator and Target) in below code- Which I am able to get it

Now, I want to have a condition for the functions (source, Operator and Target)which if it satisfies the IF condition >> then it should redirect the file name which it pass all the validation (SOURCE,OPERATOR,TARGET) and move the file name to another locatoion

i.e., for Example

```
def source():
            if sourceName_check:
                print("sourceName is vaild and starts with ES_:", sourceName_check) ---->>O/P TRUE >> pick that file and store in different directory/folder
            else:
                print("sourceName not starting with ES_: ", sourceName_check)
```

Output: IF condition is TRUE-- THEN >> PRINT the file name and >>> store in another directory

I am reading all JSON file and passing as input (ie., .JSON) and passing to all the functions. ALL FUNCTIONS WILL BE ITERATED FOR ALL FILES

Below is the entire code - Please HELP to get my solution . Thanks!
############################################################################

```
#!/bin/python
import os, json
import sys

path_to_json = "C:/Users/lm989970/Downloads/flows"


def main():
    for file_json in os.listdir(path_to_json):
        if file_json.endswith('.json'):
            print("""""######starting######""")
            print(file_json)
            try:
                 with open("{}/{}".format(path_to_json,file_json), 'r') as json_file:
                    json_data = json.load(json_file)

            except Exception as e  :
                print (e)
                print("JSON File is Invalid")

            else:
                print("JSON File is Valid")
                ReadFile = json_data['flow']
                get_status(ReadFile)
                source(ReadFile)
                operators(ReadFile)
                target(ReadFile)


def get_status(ReadFile):
    for index in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'])):
        ReadStatus = ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]["status"]
        print("status is : ", ReadStatus)


def source(ReadFile):
    for index in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'])):
        for i in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]['topics'])):
            ReadSource = ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]["topics"][i]['name']
            print('sourceName is : ', ReadSource)
            sourceName_check = ReadSource.startswith('ES_')

            if sourceName_check:
                print("sourceName is vaild and starts with ES_:", sourceName_check)
            else:
                print("sourceName is not starting with ES_:", sourceName_check)


def operators(ReadFile):
    for index in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'])):
        for i in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]['operators'])):
            ReadOperators = ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]["operators"][i]['name']
            print('Operators are : ', ReadOperators)
            operatorCheck = ReadOperators.startswith(("TRNS_", "FIL", "LKP_", "AGG_", "SSP_", "PAG_"))

            if operatorCheck:
                print("operator is vaild and starts with:", operatorCheck)
            else:
                print("operator is not starting with TRNS_:", operatorCheck)



def target(ReadFile):
    for index in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'])):
        for i in range(0, len(ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]['targets'])):
            ReadTarget = ReadFile['flowVersions'][index]["targets"][i]['name']
            print('targetName is : ', ReadTarget)
            targetName_check = ReadTarget.startswith('TGT_')

            if targetName_check:
                print("targetName is vaild and starts with TGT_:", targetName_check)
            else:
                rint("targetName is not starting with TGT_:", operatorCheck)


main()
```

Comment: it is not very clear what the question is

Comment: In each IF conditions present in the SOURCE, OPERATORS AND TARGET function.. I want to copy files which is in path_to_json to another_location (OnLy when IF is validated true). Hope this clarifies

Comment: have you ever done a google search, within 1 minute I found the solution

Comment: This medium is for share the knowledge, I did googled with whatever I searched for but not sure how ti implement. If you can help here it's fine, if not don't take advantage to argue. Please make others utilise this forums. I am not versed in python so I posted :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't program BASIC in python.

Refactored part of you code.

Have a look at `os.path.join`

Your function `target` will not run

```
def main():
    for file_json in os.listdir(path_to_json):
        if not file_json.endswith('.json'): continue
        print("""""######starting######""")
        print(file_json)
        try:
             with open("{}/{}".format(path_to_json,file_json), 'r') as json_file:
                json_data = json.load(json_file)
                print("JSON File is Valid")
                flowVersions = json_data['flow']['flowVersions']
                get_status(flowVersions)
                source(flowVersions)
                operators(flowVersions)
                target(flowVersions)

        except Exception as e  :
            print (e)
            print("JSON File is Invalid")

def get_status(flowVersions):
    for flow in flowVersions:
        print("status is : ", flow["status"])

def source(flowVersions):
    for flow in flowVersions:
        for topic in flow['topics']:
            name = topic['name']
            print('sourceName is : ', name)
            sourceName_check = name.startswith('ES_')

            if sourceName_check:
                print("sourceName is vaild and starts with ES_:")
            else:
                print("sourceName is not starting with ES_:")
```

Comment: I'm at initial stage of python.. and can you help me what you mentioned with os.path.join? Not sure where you mentioned.. can you help me with the code to achieve it? The TARGET function and entire code works for me( I had a typo when pasting it)

Comment: @Lakshmi2696 the variable `operatorCheck` is not a typo, it will not run. `os.path.join` look in the module `os.path`

Comment: It works for me when I run in my pipeline.. the execution output looks like this.. only thing is I'm not sure where to use and place os.path.join in my code.. to try with your suggestion.  Sample logs below
&!!)
('Operators are : ', u'TRANS_EXTRACT')
('operator is not starting with TRNS_:', False)
('Operators are : ', u'TRNS_EXTRACT_OLD&NEW_JSON')....not able to post pics here

Comment: @Lakshmi2696 why post pictures if all you want to show is text, then there is no need for me to type if in if I want to use it